# RabbitMQ-Unacked message count in a queue increases as listener starts and unacked messages are processed by listener

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Im trying to process the messages in dead letter queue with a dedicated rabbitMQ listener configured with customised container factory with prefetch count >1.

I'm able to consume messages from dead letter queue but the messages are getting moved from ready to unacked on listener start.

The listener/Consumer is able to process those messages.But on application restart those unacked messages are getting moved to ready

Suppose I have 100 messages in Dead letter Queue and I defined a listener with prefetch count as 10.

After listener start up
Consumer able to process those 10 messages but in Dead letter queue contains 90 as ready and 10 as unacked.As processing continues unacked is getting increased by 10

After application restart ,Those unacked messages are again moving back to ready in dead letter queue and available to listener again

please guide me on this

```
Config:
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenercontainerFactory prefetchFactory(connectionFactory){
SimpleRabbitListenercontainerFactory factory=new SimpleRabbitListenercontainerFactory ();
factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
factory.setPrefetchCount(10);
factory.setTimeOut(10000);

}
```

Here
`factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO)` is not working for consumer

```
Listener:
@RabbitListener(queues="dlq.queue",containerFactory="prefetchFactory")
public class Consumer{
@Rabbithandler
public void onReceive(Message m){
   Sysout.println("Message received:" +m.toString());
}
}
```

@GarryRussell

Comment: The default acknowledge mode is AUTO - what you are describing makes no sense; with AUTO the container will ack the message when the listener exits normally; try turning on DEBUG logging to see if it helps you understand. If you can't figure it our; post a small, verifiable example application that exhibits this behavior.